If restructuring question's body can set a new expectation on the readers, and thus making it clearer to be on-topic, should this be done?
In this example question: Cognitively, where does spiritual feeling come from?, the OP already states his expectation at the end:

I ask this question to understand how people like OSHO and thousands of his variant in India could glue millions of followers without giving any material things.

I think this paragraph alone is enough to negate any opinion that the question is about personal thing. Yet, even when there seems to be a consensus that it's possible to be on-topic*, the feeling that it's off-topic is still there. I wonder why this happens.
I'm going to speculate here and assume that because it doesn't set the expectation of the readers quick and easy, so their first impression that's it's a personal stuff continues on. (I think the personal experience about him practicing Hinduism is just a supporting evidence, not the only evidence.) A related phenomenon is contextual prerequisite for understanding. Together with the cognitive burden that no one has time to distill buried information, the question is left closed.
So it seems that a simple act of putting that paragraph to the top would work. However, when I attempt to do that, it seems the text needs to be rewritten pretty much to feel natural. The edit won't change the intention of the OP, but his wording and structure would be changed noticeably.
And even if we don't need to change the wording much, changing the reader's impression could also mean changing the OP's intention as well. This is not good, and is the reason why edits shouldn't change their intention. 
The easiest (and obvious) thing to do is ask them in the comment. But in a general case which they don't reply, how should this situation be handled?

* Are questions about cognitive aspect of spirituality on-topic?

You've put a lot of meta effort into this question without really doing anything with the feedback you've received (in summary: the question was correctly closed but could be edited to change that and you can be the one to edit). Why are you so insistent? If there is an answerable on-topic question there that is different from the one now marked as duplicate, why not just ask the question yourself?

Well, one part of the reason is that I don't find the feedback is really convincing. I understand it feels off-topic, but as presented in this post, it seems that the last paragraph is not considered enough, and thus the OP's point is missed. ■ Another part is that I just want to generalize the problem. It's just that I have only referred to his question so far that makes you feel like my only purpose when asking meta questions is about it. It's the same with the OP when he wants to generalize the problem, but only back up with his experience.
